# How does a supervisor in a prison address an inmate in American English?

Tags: single-word-requests

How does a supervisor in a prison address an inmate? For example, a relative came to visit one of the inmates, so the supervisor is going to the cell (where many inmates are) and is about to call on that inmate. How would he address him then? It seems quite unlikely to me that the supervisor would address an inmate as "Mr. (Last name)"

Comment: ***"Hey, you there!***

Comment: Hey con, you've company.

Comment: Sounds like you're writing something? If you're doing research for a story or something like that, why not contact someone directly in the field?

Comment: @Armen - But what if he in that kind of situation when he doesn't see the needed inmate yet? For example in the yard when all the inmates are taking a walk. Then, I guess he would have to identify him somehow by his last name or in some other way.

Comment: @Sam - I am not writing anything and am not doing any research. I just watched a movie in my native language and saw a scene in a prison there. And realized that, while knowing how they would do this in my language, I have no idea how this is done in English.

Comment: @brilliant: I was obviously just kidding :)

Comment: What's about *First name + sur name*?!

Comment: @Armen - Ooops. I am sorry I didn't get that

Comment: See the original movie in American English, maybe?

Comment: @Em1 - May be so. I don't know. Do you think they would use a title first? Like "inmate Michael Johnson, your wife has come to visit you" or something like that.

Comment: @Kris - That would take a lot of time, plus, I am not in an English speaking country at the moment. I think here I will get a quicker answer.

Comment: I can only say how they do in *Prison Break*. And there they didn't say *inmate*, *Mr* or whatever before.

Comment: @Em1 - I see. Thank you. Why wouldn't you reply as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Javert addressed his prisoners only by number... according to the musical.

Comment: I don't think this can be feasibly answered. It's like asking how two people in any relationship address each other--it's not uniform. Take two friends: in Korean, there is marked politeness based on seniority. Not so in English where terms of address can vary wherever you go.

Comment: @simchona - Yet everybody would address a president as "Mr. President" or would address professor as "professor", not?

Comment: Some professors are called "doctor".

Comment: @simchona To the eternal dismay of licensed physicians everywhere.

Comment: How in the world did this question get closed as "not constructive"?  How does it not fit the Q&A format or not involve "facts, references, or specific expertise"?

Comment: @chaos I agree that this question isn't "not constructive", but since I believe that it is "too localized", I see no particular need to reopen this question only to reclose it immediately thereafter.

Comment: @waiwai933: That seems more plausible, but I'm still not seeing it.  No comments or answers have raised an issue of significant regional difference in the matter.  Is there any evidence that the question is, in fact, too localized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never been in a prison, but in fiction, guards generally address inmates by their last names, without honorific: *Johnson, you have a visitor.*  In a more formal situation, full names without honorific might be used: *Michael Leroy Johnson, you are hereby released from the custody of this prison.*  An especially cold guard or warden might use the inmate's number: *Hey 24601, get back to work.*

Answer (score 3):

Last name is usual.  An announcement where the supervisor does not necessarily know that last name will be specific enough may be of the form first name, last name; last name, first name; or last name, first initial.  "Mr. Last Name" would pretty much only be used to put the inmate on notice that this is a particularly formal, and therefore particularly threatening, interaction.  Identification numbers are almost never used.

Also note that in the United States, the preferred term for someone in the supervisory role you describe is "corrections officer", or CO ("see-oh") for short; inmates who are not specifically trying to be unpleasant will usually use the term CO.  Corrections officers look down on the concept of being a "guard" as a sort of low-rent, mindless warehousing function, whereas the job they do is felt to be considerably more demanding.  They do *not* like to be called guards.

Comment: You can call them *badge*, too. At least in movies it is often said.

Comment: @Em1: Doesn't happen in real life in the United States.

Comment: @chaos I’m sorry that you know this, but I thank you for the info. :)

Comment: @tchrist: Ain't no thang. :)